# jsonlite: toJSON on object from Python's requests package leads to arrays, direct call to API does not

Tags: r, python-requests, httr, jsonlite

I'm playing around with some Fantasy Premier League data available through an API.

Desired result, nested dataframes, is achieved when running the following code:

```
library(jsonlite)
url <- "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static"
fromJSON(url)
```

More data is obtainable if you log in. I can't get the `httr` package working with the API, read somewhere that it stopped working after an SSL change a while back.

I'm able to log in and fetch data by going through Python, but I end up with different json.
The code below illustrates the problem. After going through Python, values are placed in arrays (note the brackets in the bottom json output):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

# No authentication

# API url
bootstrapUrl <- "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static"

# Desired result
fromJSON(bootstrapUrl) %>% 
  toJSON() %>% 
  substr(., 1, 100)
#> {"phases":[{"id":1,"name":"Overall","num_winners":3,"start_event":1,"stop_event":38},{"id":2,"name":


# With authentication

library(reticulate)

use_python("/usr/bin/python3.6")
source_python("~/Projects/pl/api_request.py")
### api_request.py
#
#  import requests
#  
#  def py_get_json(subdomain):
#    session = requests.session()
#    apiUrl = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/"
#    loginUrl = 'https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/'
#    payload = {
#     'password': '',
#     'login': '',
#     'redirect_uri': 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login',
#     'app': 'plfpl-web'
#    }
#    session.post(loginUrl, data=payload)
#    targetUrl = apiUrl + subdomain
#    
#    return session.get(targetUrl).json()
#
###

subdomain <- "bootstrap-static"
json <- py_get_json(subdomain)

json %>%
  toJSON() %>% 
  substr(., 1, 100)
#> {"phases":[{"id":[1],"name":["Overall"],"num_winners":[3],"start_event":[1],"stop_event":[38]},{"id"
```

I'm guessing this has to do with how the Python object is returned to R via `reticulate`. I'm looking for an easy fix, is there any functionality within `jsonlite` that can sort this out?

Comment: Try `toJSON(..., auto_unbox = TRUE`)

Comment: Indeed, problem solved. Thank you!